# App crashing when dismissing a view controller in portrait

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have viewcontroller X and viewcontroller Y.

viewController X presents Y, Viewcontroller X should only be shown in portrait mode but Y can rotate to whatever mode it wants.

When I dismiss viewController Y in landscape mode, I get the following error.
In line:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

error:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation must return a supported interface orientation!'

In X Controller, I have:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}


- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

In Y controller I have:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

This was running OK with ios 6 but is causing issues now in xcode /ios7. Now, even though I'm dismissing Y and getting back to X in landscape mode, I have it set to prefer portrait, so shouldn't it just force portrait mode regardless of my having the device in landscape?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work, and I think you already tried this. But I would suggest to change the `NO` to `YES` on `shouldAutorotate` in `X`

Comment: This wasn't it, but I had not tried it. I tried it with the same result. Turns out I was looking at the wrong file, because this is in a tab view controller, it was looking for the supported orientation on the last view loaded I added the prefered method to that and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

add this before dismiss the child viewController:

[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait]
                                forKey:@"orientation"];

suppose your parent is in portrait

Answer (score 0):

Return `YES` in your `shouldAutorotate` method. Maybe you have been doing this in the wrong view controller.

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the OP's question, as they mention having already done this with no success. Can you expand on why you feel this answer will help?

Comment: I believe now it does. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to override `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation` as it will inherit a value based on the rotation of your dismissing view controller. If this value then doesn't align with your view controllers supported interface orientation the app will crash.

```
    /// Returns `.portrait` as the default preferred interface orientation for presentation.
    ///
    /// - Important: It's important to explicitly set this value to a value which is aligned with `supportedInterfaceOrientations`. Not doing so can lead to crashes.
    /// In certain scenarios, if not set explicitly this value will be inherited from a dismissing view controller. The application will crash if the dismissing view controller was rotated to an orientation which isn't supported by
    /// this view controller. (*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation 'landscapeRight' must match a supported
    /// interface orientation: 'portrait'!')
    override public var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
        return .portrait
    }
```